# Two subdomains to two different hosts

Tags: ssl, dns

For example, let's say I have **"example.com."** Can I configure http://www.example.com to be hosted on http://www.squarespace.com and http://app.example.com to be hosted on http://www.webflow.com/? Right now I already have the **"@"** A record pointing to the Squarespace IP addresses and the **"www"** CNAME pointing to Squarespace.

I tried pointing the app A record to the webflow IP addresses, but when I visit app.example.com I get the following error:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection app.example.com sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. A subdomain is considered as an extension or a child item of the root domain and it can have its own properties, such has pointing to different IPs/websites etc.

The error you are getting could be due to a misconfigured DNS record at your registrar/NS (cloudflare/fastly etc) or SSL settings on Webflow. Follow the [steps](https://university.webflow.com/lesson/connect-a-subdomain) provided by webflow, you cannot point it to webflow's IP, you have to point to a CNAME they will provide in the format of (myproject.webflow.io). Also check if your CNAME is properly set to proxy-ssl if applicable. Else for a subdomain it seems there's an **Enable SSL** slider button to check. Finally ensure you make app subdomain as the default site on Webflow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Ked! I already have "www" pointed to Squarespace. Is it possible to use a different subdomain (e.g. "app") for Webflow and get around the SSL error?

Comment: Sorry I got mixed up with the domains, I've fixed that and updated the link as well, can you give it a try? It's seems very specific to your case so I think that will help.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!